# AWS CLI returns [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I've installed AWS CLI via msi-installer. Files are present in the installation directory, path is set. When I run `aws --version` I get the following response: `aws-cli/2.1.29 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`, so it seems like working. But when I try to run any aws command, for example `aws sts get-caller-identity --profile <profile-name>` I get the following error: `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`. All answers I found in google refer to setting path. Any ideas how to fix this?

UPD. First error in exception trace:

```
2021-03-24 17:22:15,988 - MainThread - botocore.utils - DEBUG - Caught retryable HTTP exception while making metadata service request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://169.254.169.254/latest/api/token"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
  File "urllib3\util\connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
  File "urllib3\util\connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
OSError: [WinError 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

Comment: Run with `--debug` and see if helps you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Colleague from another department helped me to solve my problem. He reassembled the aws-okta.exe binary. That's his comment:

> it looked like something in your host env was was making sys.arg[0] resolve to the absolute path for the  aws-okta binary instead of the basepath (aka filename). I changed aws-okta creds so that it now always resolves absolute path for the aws-okta binary and then deconstructs it to determine the basepath